# How to disable deprecation warnings in Ember.js?

Tags: ember.js

I've written up an application that uses Ember Data. It's passing all it's tests and running as expected, however, something is causing a repeated deprecation warning to be thrown into console.

I'd like to know how to disable these warnings in Ember.

Comment: What is the message that appears in console?

Comment: `DEPRECATION: Ember.metaPath is deprecated and will be removed from future releases.` It's an documented issue with Ember Data - I'm not curious how to fix it; I just want to turn off the warnings.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can just do `Ember.deprecate = function(){}` in your application.js file and that should disable ember deprecation warnings.

Comment: Good idea to put this in the app.js file in your Ember-cli apps.  That way when that file gets overwritten, when you upgrade ember-cli, you get to make sure you see all the latest deprecations.

Comment: The problem with this when using ember-cli is that libraries may already be loaded before the function is overwritten, causing deprecations still being shown from the libs.

Comment: There is update - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19435115/how-to-disable-deprecation-warnings-in-ember-js/35366612#35366612

Comment: In modern Ember (4.12 and later) there is no Ember object anymore, you need a dummy `registerDeprecationHandler` from `'@ember/debug'`, see other answers below.

Answer (score 11):

It's always good to consider deprecations, but if you want to just turn them off entirely add the following 2 lines to your main **app.js** file.

```
Ember.deprecate = function(){};
Ember.warn = function(i){};
```

Answer (score 7):

My suggestion here, so you won't completely miss the deprecation warnings - they're there for a reason, right?

These are simplified versions of what `deprecate` would do, but logging to DEBUG (so you can filter them out easily) and without the stacktrace (for simplicity). They'll also not show repeated messages:

**CoffeeScript**:

```
Ember.deprecate = (->
  already_shown = []
  (msg, test, opt)->
    return false if test
    if already_shown.indexOf(msg) == -1
      warning = "DEPRECATION: #{msg}"
      warning += " See: #{opt.url}" if opt.url
      console.debug warning
    already_shown.push msg
)()
```

**JS**:

```
Ember.deprecate = (function() {
  var already_shown = [];
  return function (msg, test, opt) {
    if (test) return false;
    if (already_shown.indexOf(msg) === -1) {
      var warning = 'DEPRECATION: ' + msg;
      if (opt.url) {
        warning += ' See: ' + opt.url;
      }
      console.debug(warning);
    }
    already_shown.push(msg);
  };
})();
```

Comment: This sound like a great suggestion, but I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined` on the `if (opt.url) {` line... :(

Comment: @JoeCzucha `if (opt && opt.url) { …`

Answer (score 6):

Modifed for **Ember 2.3** version (thank's to [igorsantos07](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30290813/344172))

```
const alreadyShownFactory = () => {
  let alreadyShown = [];
  return (msg, test, opt) => {
    if (test)
      return false;

    if( alreadyShown.indexOf(msg) === -1 ) {
      let warning = 'DEPRECATION: ' + msg;
      if(opt && opt.url) {
        warning += ' See: ' + opt.url;
      }
      console.warn(warning);
      alreadyShown.push(msg);
    }
  };
};
Ember.deprecate = alreadyShownFactory();
Ember.warn = alreadyShownFactory();

//see https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.3.0/configuring-ember/handling-deprecations/
Ember.Debug.registerDeprecationHandler((() => {
  let alreadyShown = [];
  return (message, options, next) => {
    if(alreadyShown.indexOf(message) === -1) {
      next(message, options);
      alreadyShown.push(message);
    }
  };
})());
```

Comment: Any updates to v3+

Answer (score 4):

For **Ember 3.8** below code in **app/initializers/deprecation.js** worked for me. This disables the deprecations while running tests. You can modify according to your needs.

```js
import { registerDeprecationHandler } from '@ember/debug';

export function initialize() {
  registerDeprecationHandler((message, options, next) => {
    if (options && options.until && options.until !== '2.0.0') {
      return;
    } else {
      next(message, options);
    }
  });
}

export default { initialize };
```

Took this from the [docs](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/configuring-ember/handling-deprecations/)

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for this in Ember >=2.0.0, you have to change this in:

```
Ember.Logger.warn = () => {}
Ember.Logger.deprecate = () => {}
```

Answer (score 0):

For **Ember 4.12** (and probably later) this worked for me in `app/app.js`:

```js
import Application from '@ember/application';
// [...]

import { registerDeprecationHandler } from '@ember/debug';

export default class App extends Application {
  // [...]
  dummy = registerDeprecationHandler((message, options, next) => {
    // shush deprecations
  });
}

loadInitializers(App, config.modulePrefix);
```