# How do I turn off deprecation warnings in ember.js 2.3?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I've seen this:

[How to disable deprecation warnings in Ember.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19435115/how-to-disable-deprecation-warnings-in-ember-js)

and this:

https://coderwall.com/p/ekugbw/turn-off-ember-deprecation-warnings

and now my code looks like this:

```
//app.js
import Ember from 'ember';

import Resolver from 'ember-resolver';
import loadInitializers from 'ember/load-initializers';
import config from './config/environment';

Ember.deprecate = () => {};
Ember.warn = function(i){};
```

and my environment file right now includes this:

```
EmberENV: {
      LOG_STACKTRACE_ON_DEPRECATION: false,
      FEATURES: {
        // Here you can enable experimental features on an ember canary build
        // e.g. 'with-controller': true
      }
    },
```

This has gotten me half the results I wanted: the log stacktrace is gone, but I still get the one line deprecation warnings. While I will be using these warnings to as a guideline to refactor in the future, the logging of these deprecation warnings is interfering with my debugging process. I need them gone - temporarily. The source of these deprecations are most likely the libraries I use (legacy-controller, legacy-view, auth0, etc.) but regardless, I need to silence these warnings so that they do not pollute the console.

I'm using Ember 2.3, and I suspect the solutions I found (linked in this question) are for Ember 1.13.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to selectively enable deprecations for future work, I suggest using [ember-cli-deprecations-workflow](https://github.com/mixonic/ember-cli-deprecation-workflow).

You can install it with `ember install ember-cli-deprecation-workflow`, and then follow the instructions on the README to populate the whitelist.

Answer (score 0):

You need to stop the loggin of deprecations. Try this:

```
RAISE_ON_DEPRECATION = false;
```

Comment: That doesn't work. It is false by default, and setting it to true causes a deprecation to raise an error.

Comment: ^ can confirm. It's false by default; true will stop the application when a deprecation is flagged.