# How to remove these deprecation on console on ember^2.0

Tags: ember.js

while refreshing my site i am always getting some deprecation like this on console :

```
 A property of <Ember.OutletView:ember666> was modified inside the didUpdate hook. You should never change properties on components, services or models during didUpdate because it causes significant performance degradation. [deprecation id: ember-views.dispatching-modify-property]
```

How to remove these deprecation on console on ember^2.0 
I am not using Ember CLI.

Comment: The error is pretty much self explanatory. If you ask how to refactor it then post your "didUpdate" hook code and maybe something can be done differently.

Comment: Yes But it works fine...with some Deprecation .

Comment: Yes it may work now, however in the future it may not.

Comment: My project is to large so it take time for change and i don't  have time for that now .so want to remove in only console.

Comment: Well unfortunately this is how deprecation removal works, if you havent updated code by each ember version and jumped straight to Ember2 . We removed our deprecations for 2 weeks. You either find time to get rid of that old code or you be in great technial debt. However if you dont have time now you can just hide "deprecations" by changing console "all" to "errors"

Comment: @kristjanreinhold you don't *need* to update every single release, bar security fixes. 2.4 is the first LTS release of Ember, so there's even less pressure to update.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable deprecation warnings in Ember.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19435115/how-to-disable-deprecation-warnings-in-ember-js)

Comment: @locks It's much easier to update step by step rather than taking that huge step at once.

Answer (score 2):

Usually it means, that you need to do the work inside the didReceiveAttrs method, rather than the didUpdate. However, it you must have it in didUpdate, you can do something like this:

```
didUpdate() {
  Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, => {
    // some code
  });
}
```

However it most likely will do some rendering twice (however it already does it twice - hence the deprecation).

Answer (score 0):

Romans solution worked well for me, except for some syntax problems. I needed to set a default value to a child component. Heres the code:

```
initDefValue: function() {
    const valEmpty = Ember.isEmpty(this.get("value"));
    if (valEmpty) {
        Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, () => {
            this.sendAction("initValue", this);
        });
    }
}.on("didReceiveAttrs"),
```